# Setting Cookie with jQuery on root path (/) not accessible to subdirectories on internet explorer 9

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, path

I am setting a cookie with jQuery on the root directory with the following code:

```
$.cookie('key', 'value', {
    path: '/',
    expires: 30
});
```

I am then reading the cookie throughout the website, but IE9 will only find the cookie on the home page (`www.example.com/`), not other pages (`www.example.com/subdir` or `www.example.com/subdir/sub`).

In fact when I `var_dump($_COOKIE)` on any subdirectory page all I get is `array(0) {}`

I can view the cookie just fine by going to cache -> view cookie information.  It is there and set to `/`.

Works perfectly in all other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cookie is as below :

```
$.cookie('key', 'value', { path: '/', domain: 'example.com', expires: 30 });
```

For more information check [**Cookies and domains**](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/cookies-and-domains/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That almost worked.  I set the cookie with the domain, but now if I set the cookie on a subdirectory page, the cookie is not found on the home(root) page.  My var_dump($_COOKIE) displays an array of other cookies, but my cookie is not found.  Again I can view the cookie from the cache -> view cookie information, and now the cookie is found with var_dump($_COOKIE) on only a few seemingly random subdir pages.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, we came to the conclusion that the problem was actually a caching issue with W3 Total Cache.